# Streaming to parquet files not happy with flink 1.6.1

Tags: apache-flink

I'm very new to flink (and parquet/hadoop for that matter) so I'm most certainly doing something really stupid. I'm trying to create a sink which will dump my data source to a parquet file.

My code looks like:

```scala
val streamEnv = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
streamEnv.setParallelism(1);
streamEnv.enableCheckpointing(100, CheckpointingMode.EXACTLY_ONCE);

val sink = StreamingFileSink.forBulkFormat(outputPath, ParquetAvroWriters.forReflectRecord(classOf[MyClass])).build()
testSource.addSink(sink)
```

Unfortunately I'm not getting the exception I was earlier, but it's still not generating correct output. I'm currently getting a single .part-xxx file with 4B of data in it. There are about 20,000 records in this stream so that doesn't seem right.

Before I started writing this question I was getting a method not found exception from ParquetAvroWriters.java at line 84.

That code looks like:

```scala
return AvroParquetWriter.<T>builder(out)
    .withSchema(schema)
    .withDataModel(dataModel)
    .build();
```

The `AvroParquetWriter` method signature is:

```java
public static <T> Builder<T> builder(Path file)
```

But the parameter at the time ParquetAvroWriters.java calls it is a StreamOutputFile hence the no method error.

I'm using flink 1.6.1 and parquet-hadoop/parquet-avro 1.10.0. How exactly should I be setting things up to write a parquet file?

This is getting most frustrating - I can't even find an example that compiles.

Answer (score 4):

After reading the coments of the people, I have create a project with the same code( similar), but you can compile and execute.

```scala
object CustomSource {

  case class TextOut(data:String )

  def generateRandomStringSource(out: SourceContext[TextOut]) = {
    val lines = Array("how are you", "you are how", " i am fine")
    while (true) {
      val index = Random.nextInt(3)
      Thread.sleep(200)
      out.collect(TextOut(lines(index)))
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val streamEnv =
      StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

    streamEnv.setParallelism(1)
    streamEnv.enableCheckpointing(10000,
      CheckpointingMode.EXACTLY_ONCE)
    val sink = StreamingFileSink.forBulkFormat(new
        Path("file:///tmp/test2"),
      ParquetAvroWriters.forReflectRecord(classOf[TextOut])).build()

    val customSource = streamEnv.addSource(generateRandomStringSource
      _)

    customSource.print()

    customSource.addSink(sink)

    streamEnv.execute()
  }
}
```

I have created a project to show how is running, and the minimal things(jar,ect) that it is necessary.

This is the link : https://github.com/jose1003/flinkparquet

BR

Jose

Comment: Please don't post link only answers. Always include a summary of your link to your answer so that your answer stays helpful in case the link target gets removed, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers for more information.

Comment: I have provided a solution. At then it is not enough with the code, you need to have all correct, in this case the pom.xml also.

Comment: Its not a link only answer any more.

Answer (score 2):

Flink's `StreamingFileSink` using a bulk format automatically uses the `OnCheckpointRollingPolicy`. This means that results are only materialized whenever a checkpoint completes. This is required to provide exactly once processing guarantees.

I assume that you are using a `CollectionSource` as a test input and that the processing of this input takes less than the specified `100ms`. Consequently, no checkpoint can complete and also no results will be written. Flink won't trigger a checkpoint once the input is completely consumed. Thus, all events after the last completed checkpoint won't be visible.

Try to decrease the checkpoint interval, increase the number of elements in your `CollectionSource` or write your own `TestingSource extends SourceFunction` which runs at least as long as a single checkpoint interval (e.g. with a sleep). That way, Flink should be able to complete a checkpoint and, thus, write out the results to the specified directory.

Comment: Hmmm, so I tried this and it changed the logging behavior but not the final outcome.

Comment: Hmmm, so I tried this (changed it down to 10mS) and it changed the logging behavior but not the final outcome.

I got several "Completed checkpoint 3 for job b17241e8482642131ad342f0cf42779f (2624 bytes in 206 ms)." in the logs.

Then a whole bunch of:
`Checkpoint triggering task Source: Custom File Source (1/1) of job b17241e8482642131ad342f0cf42779f is not in state RUNNING but FINISHED instead. Aborting checkpoint.`

I'm still just getting a whopping 4B in the temp parquet file. If I save the source to a csv file via writeAsCsv I get 14,921 lines of output so the source seems ok.

Comment: Which input source do you use? Do you use `StreamExecutionEnvironment#fromCollection`? If so, then `10ms` might also be too high because processing of 20000 records can happen really fast. Could you try to define your own `SourceFunction` where you insert a short sleep after each record emission.

Comment: It's reading a text file from S3 (streamEnv.readTextFile). To be sure I added a 1mS in an intermediate map (converting each JSON text line). 

Still get the same result unfortunately...

But, I also get a TON of these: `Checkpoint triggering task Source: Custom File Source (1/1) of job 48da965be54163702cc4b0ffe837a005 is not in state RUNNING but FINISHED instead. Aborting checkpoint`

Comment: I think the problem is that you use the `ContinuousFileMonitoringFunction` with `FileProcessingMode#PROCESS_ONCE`. Please set it to `PROCESS_CONTINUOUSLY` by using the `StreamExecutionEnvironment#readFile(FileInputFormat, String, FileProcessingMode, long)`. That way, the source won't terminate and you will be able to take a checkpoint.

Comment: Ugh sadness! So I tried that and it does indeed not terminate. But, it also never writes anything to the parquet file...

Comment: Can you maybe share a working example of your code with example data with me? Then I could try to debug it.